# Java - Get a given objects name from another class

Tags: java, object

I have a basic understanding of OOP concepts, but here is a question I currently have.

Say I create this object:

```
Test test1 = new Test();
```

I then call a function within this Object

```
test1.toString();
```

And when overriding that toString() method I want to get the 'test1' object name from the main class file, so I can print it out like so...

```
System.out.println( "This is a test " + test1.toString() );
```

Prints:

**This is a test test1**

Thank you

Comment: Sorry i'm confused, what is your question?

Comment: You can store the 'test1' name in a private attribute and then use that value in a method.

Comment: What is the object name in `Test test1 = new Test(); Test test2 = test1;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a local variable is only meaningful at compile time.  There is no way to obtain the name of a reference.

Note: the reference and the Object are two different things.

What you can do is get the name of a field, however there is no way to find from an object where the object has been assigned.

The normal way to give an Object a name, is to give a field e.g. `name`

```
Test test1 = new Test("test1");
String str = test1.getName();
```

For `enum` there is an implicit name.

```
enum BuySell {
    Buy, Sell;
}

BuySell bs = BuySell.Buy;
String s = bs.name(); // implicitly defined for all Enum
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Peter